# PHP Post request working in Postman but not in React with Axios

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

- I have a server written in PHP and it have some routes
- The routes work fine with postman
- But when I use React with Axios it gives error
- Here is the PHP code

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

and here is how I make request with Postman
This is my raw JSON data that I feed in postman

```
{
    "data1" : "data1"
}
```

This is how I make the post request with React and Axios

```js
await axios("url", {
        data: JSON.stringify({ "data1" , "data1" }),
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
```

The url is same , but it's giving network error

I want my axios request to get completed as it get's completed on postman

[image]

[image]

I have also tried this config but not working

```
<?php


// Allow from any origin
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]))
{
    // You can decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is something you want to allow, or as we do here, just allow all
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
}
else
{
    //No HTTP_ORIGIN set, so we allow any. You can disallow if needed here
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 600");    // cache for 10 minutes

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "OPTIONS")
{
    
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD"]))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"); //Make sure you remove those you do not want to support

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"]))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    //Just exit with 200 OK with the above headers for OPTIONS method
    exit(0);
}
//From here, handle the request as it is ok
```

Comment: Can you show the postmen screenshot please

Comment: I have updated the question , now you can see the postman headers

Comment: Can you add the resulting network error? You tryed adding the "origin" header to the react request?

Comment: Hey @Guille I have added the network error , and yeah , I dont think i need to add origin since i have done something like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *"

Comment: So you're receiving a HTTP 500 error in postman, what are you expecting in Axios? Are using the `.catch` method to handle this 500 error?

Comment: It's giving 500 since there was no product to delete , It gives 200 when there is something to delete, GET request working find in postman as well as  React but not POST request , I think it's because of the preflight thing

Comment: Can you show the endpoint function because I noticed that you stringify your data, do you decode it in the back-end

Comment: Yes I decoded it , I think the problem is CORS , since if it's working in postman , the logic must be correct

Comment: on your localhost try adding https like https://localhost:5173. the console or the network must be showing some error can you also post those if the https does not work

Comment: `I think the problem is CORS ,`...why? Are you actually getting a CORS error? Have you checked this in the browser's console? It's very unclear what, if any, meaningful debugging you've actually done here. Remember we can't run your code so you need to report on it accurately and do detailed debugging to identify a clear, specific problem. You said `it gives error` but then didn't tell us what the error actually is. Don't you think that would be useful information??

Comment: `It's giving 500 since there was no product to delete `...that shouldn't happen. 500 indicates a crash and an error. There being nothing to delete should not cause a crash. It should simply not delete anything, and then finish the script without any errors. If you want to be smarter, it could output a message saying there was nothing to delete. But it definitely should not crash in that situation

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running your code locally, try using electronjs. It solves CORS problems. And you won't even need the axios.

Answer (score 0):

OK guyz , now I understood the problem ,
I hosted my PHP API in 000webhost , and this host provider does not support the OPTIONS method , which is the pre-flight request method , made by browser only (not by postman) . That's why it was working in Postman but not in React.